# Can we Join an INT to a Varchar in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, casting, inner-join

I have a pretty simple query that should return a bunch of records, but nothing is actually returned.  My SQL looks like this.

```
Select fsm.date, fsm.eno, nat.`PS Loc Code`, nat.Site
FROM v_fsm as fsm
INNER JOIN national as nat
ON fsm.eno = cast(nat.Site as int)
WHERE (fsm.date >= '2020-12-01' AND nat.day >= '2020-12-01')
```

When I look atv the field types, IN see that `eno is INT` and `Site is VARCHAR`.  When I run the SQL, no records are returned, but I can see eno has some records with 123000 and Site has some records with 123000.  Thanks.

Comment: How about length...maybe in your varchar fields you have spaces that are not visible...maybe if you trim it? Like `fsm.eno = TRIM(nat.Site)`

Comment: That's a good idea.  I just tried that.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting no results.

Comment: Cast value to int is redundant. MySQL do implicit type casting so `select 123000 = '123000';` returns true. Looks as WHERE condition filter out all rows

Comment: Another option some invisible symbols in varchar column. Try to run `SELECT * FROM national nat WHERE nat.Site = 12300;`

Comment: What do you see if you do `SELECT cast(site as int) from national WHERE site = '123000'`?

Comment: @Barmar, I am getting some results from that.

Comment: And do the results contain the number `123000`?

Comment: Yes it does.  I'm still a bit confused as to why my original query returns no results.

Comment: Apparently...this is working now.  I don't know what was happening before, but I was logging in to the DB through a VPN and the performance was spotty, at best.  Maybe that caused some weirdness.   In the end, this worked : ON fsm.eno = nat.Site  I think the DB handles these joins intelligently and resolves any issues with JOINS automatically.